# TextView on top of StateListDrawable

Tags: android, textview, imageview, statelistdrawable

I'm trying to get my TextViews and ImageView to show up on top of a LinearLayout which I added a StateListDrawable to. I create my buttons like this:

```
    protected StateListDrawable generateButton(String[] colors, String[] selectColors, String strokeColor, int strokewidth)
{
    int[] iColors = CurrentTheme.getIntColorArrayFromStringArray(colors);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR, iColors);
    gd.setCornerRadius(10);
    gd.setStroke(strokewidth, Color.parseColor(strokeColor));

    int[] iSelectColors = CurrentTheme.getIntColorArrayFromStringArray(selectColors);

    GradientDrawable sgd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR, iSelectColors);
    sgd.setCornerRadius(10);
    sgd.setStroke(strokewidth, Color.parseColor(strokeColor));

    StateListDrawable slDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
    slDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, sgd);
    slDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, gd);    

    return slDrawable;
}
```

In my activity I add this drawable to a linearLayout like so:

```
_topMenuButton.setBackgroundDrawable(_theme.getPrimaryButtonDrawable());
```

The layout is included with the following line in the content view of my Activity:

```
<include layout="@layout/inc_button_menu" android:id="@+id/second_menu_button" />
```

Which in turn includes a LinearLayout which has a ImageView and two TextViews inside.

When I try to get the TextViews from the LinearLayout (which I added the StateListDrawable to in my Activity) and add Text to them the text doesn't show. Same goes for the ImageView. I'm not sure how I am able to get these Views to show up.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it wasn't the code behind but the code from the included layout. Since the code worked before with a layout file as drawable, I assumed that it wasn't this code. The problem was that I used android:weight="1" on one of the items.